# Tell me what number character in string is wrong

Tags: php, regex

I want to make a function in PHP that takes a string as argument and then tell me for example that character number 5 in the string is invalid, so i know where to look for the error, instead of just telling me that the string contains invalid characters.

Lets say i have the string "abc1x3".

```
Character 1 must be a-z to be valid.
Character 2 must be a-z to be valid.
Character 3 must be a-z to be valid.
Character 4 must be 0-9 to be valid.
Character 5 must be 0-9 to be valid.
Character 6 must be 0-9 to be valid.
```

So therefore character 5 is invalid. It should be a number, but it is x.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How are you defining the validation criteria of each position of the string?

Comment: Take the input string, and go through character by character and check according the position of that character. Checking if a character is upper case or lowercase, number or special character may not require any regexp at all.

Comment: Doesn't PHP have a built-in function to help with this? Like preg_match(), but it should say what character it failed at.

Answer (score 2):

One non-regex solution (for this specific case, in any other case you should set new rules!):

```
$str = 'abc1x3';
$arr = str_split($str);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

    //set rules, check char by char!

    if ($i < 3) {
        if (!ctype_alpha($arr[$i])) {
            echo 'Character'.($i + 1).
            'must be letter';
        }
    } else if (!ctype_digit($arr[$i])) {
        echo 'Character number '.($i + 1).
        ' must be number';
    }
}
```

EDit: Use ctype_lower() function if you want lowercase characters, or simple regex...

Comment: This is ok on a super simple case like this, if it were a complex series you would end up writing a regex engine via language level api.

Answer (score 1):

Using a modified cascading regex, you'd compare the match length to the
string length to get the position of the offending character.

`^(?:[a-z]{3}(?:\d{1,3})?|[a-z]{1,2})?`

```
 ^     
 (?:
      [a-z]{3} 
      (?:
           \d{1,3} 
      )?
   |  
      [a-z]{1,2} 
 )?
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 4 ) 
abc1
```

if ( match.length != str.length ) {  print "invalid at position match.length +1" }